# How can I make multiple jQuery animate() calls work one after another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

When I click the "aa" block, both "aa"  and "bb" animate at the same time. Does javascript issue animate() functions non-blockingly into separate threads? Or this function is entered multiple times with thousands of callbacks which use blocking-type function calls? How can I make animate() work on items one by one when needed(maybe using a timer could do but do I have to use a timer always?)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script>

        function growbits(i,j) {
            $(i).animate({ height: "500px" }); // looks working concurrently
            $(j).animate({ width: "500px"});   // with this one
        };

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="bb" style="background: #f00; height: 50px; width: 255px; margin: 10px;">asdasd</p>  
    <p id="aa" onclick="growbits(aa,bb);" style="background: #f00; height: 50px; width: 255px; margin: 10px;">
        gfhjjjgfhgkjfhkjtkjyhtkjyhkhfukhgkudfgk

    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Ive found the following code in the min.js file:

```
self.element.animate(
            $.extend(style, top && left ? { top: top, left: left } : {}), {
                duration: o.animateDuration,
                easing: o.animateEasing,
                step: function() {

                    var data = {
                        width: parseInt(self.element.css('width'), 10),
                        height: parseInt(self.element.css('height'), 10),
                        top: parseInt(self.element.css('top'), 10),
                        left: parseInt(self.element.css('left'), 10)
                    };

                    if (pr && pr.length) $(pr[0]).css({ width: data.width, height: data.height });

                    // propagating resize, and updating values for each animation step
                    self._updateCache(data);
                    self._propagate("resize", event);

                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: Depends on the javascript engine…

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a built-in `animate` function. You can see it is a method of a jQuery object. Check the jQuery source code.

Comment: Okay, Ill look into source.

Comment: you have an extra `;`

Comment: Does ';' mean parallel execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation:

> ```
> .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
> ```
>
> **complete**
>   Type: Function()
>   A function to call once the animation is complete.

So:

```
function growbits(i,j) {
    $(i).animate({ height: "500px" }, {}, 400, function () {
        $(j).animate({ width: "500px"});
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

[Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21970214/624590) works, but these days I would suggest that it might be cleaner using the options version:

`.animate( properties, options )`

As such:

`javascript
function growbits(i,j) {
  $(i).animate({ height: "500px" }, {
    duration: 400, 
    done: function () {
      $(j).animate({ width: "500px"});
    }
  });
};`

(`done` can be replaced by (the old option) `complete`, or `always`; `always`, `done`, and `fail` are the now-popular Promise events)

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, the reason I suggest this is three-fold:

1) You don't need to provide attributes that don't matter to you (in this case, easing),

2) If you decide other attributes matter, they're often trivial to add,

3) (Most importantly) when you're editing the code later you'll understand exactly what the nested function is for without having to think about it.