# Div to animate and then disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a div slide to the left and THEN disappear. I am using this code.

```
function slide_in(current_my)   {
$("#" + current_my).animate({
left: "510"
}, {
duration: 750
 });
  document.getElementById(current_my).style.display = "none"; 
}
```

if I remove the last line of code the div slides nicely to the left over 750ms. But when I add the last line the div just disappears.

I tired adding:

```
wait(750);
```

before the last line, where the 'wait' function was defined as :

```
function wait(ms)
{
var d = new Date();
var d2 = null;
do { d2 = new Date(); }
while(d2-d < ms);
}
```

but that just made the div sit there for 750ms and then disappear. Again, what I want is for the 'current_my' div to slide / animate and THEN disappear (display:none). Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Can you make codepen, jsbin with your full code so we can see it action

Comment: While an external demo reproducing your problem is a nice bonus, please [edit] your question to show the [mcve] code *in your question*. Though it's worth pointing out that that the 'answer' is probably as simple as inserting the `document.getElementById(...)...` line as the `complete` callback within the [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method. If a jQuery method doesn't work as you expect it's *always* worth checking their (mostly excellent) documentation: `http://api.jquery.com/<methodName>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make multiple jQuery animate() calls work one after another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970113/how-can-i-make-multiple-jquery-animate-calls-work-one-after-another)

Comment: You could do that with just CSS.

Comment: Don't do a wait like that, burns a hole in my lap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hide the div in complete callback

```
function slide_in(current_my)   {
   $("#" + current_my).animate({
      left: "510"
    }, 750, function() {
      document.getElementById(current_my).style.display = "none"; 
    });

}
```

[Doc reference](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the complete option of jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Also since you already have the object, there is no point in going to find it again. In your complete method, you can just use the `this` keyword and apply the hiding or any other animation directly to the object again.

```
$("#" + current_my).animate({ left: "510" }, { duration: 750 }, function() {
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Animate takes a callback when finished. 
You could

```
function slide_in(current_my)   {
    $("#" + current_my).animate({
         left: "510"
    }, {
         duration: 750
    }, function () {
         document.getElementById(current_my).style.display = "none"; 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), you would need to adjust the animation duration on the css file.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('button.btn').click(function() {
   $('div.box').addClass('animated fadeOutLeftBig');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}

div.box {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
<button class="btn">Fade Left</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly more than asked but lets make it fun.  Toss in an event to trigger the animation instead of a function, passing the location and duration numbers just for fun:

```js
$(document).on('slidehide', '.myanimate', function(event, requstedduration, whereto, shouldhide) {
  var p = $(this).position();
  $(this).animate({
    left: whereto
  }, {
    duration: requstedduration,
    start: function() {$('.silly').toggle(shouldhide);},
    complete: function() {
      $(this).toggle(!shouldhide);
    }
  });
});

$('.myanimate').on('click', function() {
  console.log('moving');
  $(this).trigger('slidehide', [750, 510, true]);
});
// just so we can restart/see again
$(document).on('click', '.silly', function() {
  console.log('restart');
  $('.myanimate').show().trigger('slidehide', [750, 10, false]);;
});
```

```css
  .myanimate {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}

.silly {
  display: none;
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myanimate">howdy there (click to trigger)</div>
<div class='silly'>Animation complete. (click to restart)</div>
```